# Can I trigger an action when a button is pressed while an edit is in progress?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, uitextfield

I have 2 text field inputs and a button. Whenever `textFieldDidEndEditing` happens, I save what the user types in.

The problem is that when you click on the button while entering data into the second textfield, it is not saved because it doesn't end editing.

Is there a way to end the editing when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your button's action, add the following line of code (should be the first line of code in the function):

```
[self.view endEditing:TRUE];
```

Note that this will also call the `textFieldDidEndEditing` function of the active text field. That being said, you may just want to have a button that dismisses the keyboard, and then the `textFieldDidEndEditing` will save the data, like this:

```
-(IBAction)yourAction {

    [self.view endEditing:TRUE];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    //Save your data
}
```